# Google Data Studio Community Visualization Doesn't Show Canvas on Dev Mode

Tags: javascript, looker-studio

I am setting up the simplest community visualization. It only draws a blue rectangular on the canvas. However, as I upload my code to google cloud bucket and add the visualization to my Google Data Studio, it does not show anything.

Here is my code: https://storage.googleapis.com/gistic_default/myViz/myViz.js

The error shown in browser is: `https://datastudio.googleusercontent.com/getThirdPartyScript?vizId=gs%3A%2F%2Fgistic_default%2FmyViz%C2%A0barChart&path=gs%3A%2F%2Fgistic_default%2FmyViz%2FmyViz.js&cacheBuster=1641850894876 net::ERR_ABORTED 500` which looks like GDS can not find the script.

Comment: The url `https://storage.googleapis.com/gistic_default/myViz/myViz.js` gives `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()` error. Make sure it exists or has public access.

Comment: The current self accepted answer "_Everything works fine after I uploaded code with linux system_" points towards this being an issue that is **not reproducible** as Google Data Studio is a web based app, thus the operating system should not be an issue...Google Chrome is the recommended browser, thus perhaps the issue may have been with using another browser or a different version of Google Chrome? In any case, a minimal reproducible example is needed to verify the issue...

Comment: Could you elaborate by providing a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? If you could replicate the scenario on a fresh Google Data Studio Report using sample data that would also be proof that it is a reproducible issue! if you could then share that Google Data Studio Report publicly and add a link in the question, it would allow fellow users to test it out. Without a Reproducible Example it would be **difficult to pinpoint a suggestion and the issue, e.g. Data Set, Data Source, Report, Fields, Chart Configuration, Temporary Outage**...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Everything works fine after I uploaded code with linux system.